# PDF is plain-text/encoded mess when downloaded from UNC share (using ASP.NET MVC 3 / IE 9)

Tags: io, internet-explorer-9, asp.net-mvc-3

I have written a controller action that checks for the existence of a PDF file and then returns the file (if found) to the browser as a download.

```
public ActionResult GetMyFile(string path)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(path)) { throw new ArgumentNullException("filename"); }

    string downloadFileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(path);
    // The worker process identity must have read access in both the file system and share
    // otherwise this always returns false.
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(path)) 
    {
        FilePathResult result = 
            File(path, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf, downloadFileName);
        return result;
    }

    return Content("no file", "text-plain");
}
```

Everything works fine, if the path parameter refers to a local path on disk (e.g. `"D:\MyFolder\MyFile.pdf"`), but when the path is a UNC path, the PDF is returned, but rendered as plain text in the browser.

Here's a snippet of what this looks like...

> %PDF-1.3
>   1 0 obj
>   << 
>   /Length 1409
>   /Filter /FlateDecode
>   >
>   stream
>   X���`I�%&/m�{J�J��t��`$ؐ@�������iG#)�*��eVe]f@�흼��{����{����;�N'���?\fdl��J�ɞ!���?~|?"~Q�����"�Iw�Ow����:O��,��'?���dg|g/����P��t�Ӄ����:}��Ç������to���}�7��q��/�>O�>�_����9!�`g������Y���`|�{�p�?�������?����ܿO����s�>���'ڜH������;��D��>��    ���?��?J��t�m����t�C���O�(i�����H������~H��7JLǎ��K�%ͧ������T1����*���S���=��.F.#�׷ww�����z�wǟҴ~���x�~���Px�������|3�j����c��)f1`��O�1�4�����b�qN̔>������跟j�jB?��݃ ����c��.���ڀ�^ofq�,�Pp���g��=Oo�
>   ��7�}��פ�>  ��m)}�~�W!�w��Q�0SR�3���2-���&-��Fhy�S�]���HiyF_���
>   �4�;Q��l�f��|]>ۍ�hc��C��64���|L�4�9Pξ�{#-�?��|���=1Tl��O�����݂6�����a֡�.fe΀:�����/��1��#�{���������?��|v��}�4�}Cw��!�`���&z�v��4�����Uj0*�&���-��������x�i�ģ����|=�9LnI7�&+�gʃ�;��U� m��
>   M��.�ޏ�D�QvT��ϯ���f���(��������0��������{_������ui�Rid�6���u��a��`x"��m��{�o$���`�
>   ����.���{@xu�8ӮR�����Ύ�r��{�m��$��O ��v����=�������X!~,E,�P����mf�2%9{��m����֍b���8���ñ��:
>   �PE��O<�e~jƄ�ߨ���?�Z���`����"�Ǟ:����D��N�ߌ����PL��0��U����F4 g�oPW�Ml��#"�~ﾗ���_�����뾯���?���mG`o�������=�bwGr/��b���?t3(�����t��=[\��O+���c������res����u��0�,G��f��̲qO��\�S��7��q̘�܀,.����Wn$��w�M%�����2ymd�I<͑U��eV�A-|�DڵDz�à�/]��J�|�ݾ'��$.\W��R�>���l|%�a�gj���0|{�R�c�������!�lwv?S��^S
>   E����z��3�����hr�{��R"C�݅o��Ac�*T��Q��IE�6XP5ˮ�j4k��v�
>       D��-��
>   endstream

**Any thoughts as to why this might be happening?**

My environment is an ASP.NET MVC 3 application running in IIS on Windows 7.
The client is Internet Explorer 9 RC running on the same machine.

The UNC path is a shared folder on the same machine as the web server, and is the same physical location used in the "local path test" (which succeeds).

For permissions I have ensured that the worker process identity for my application pool has *Read* permissions in both the file system and through the share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

Changing the final `return` statement from:

```
return Content("no file", "text-plain");
```

to

```
return null;
```

Seems to have fixed the problem. Although I'm not sure as to why that is. I would think that if the first `return` (in the *if* block) was executed, then the final one would have never come into the picture.

**I'm happy to accept someone else's answer if they can explain *why* that is.**